# CSS3 Translating different sized content from same starting position

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, transition

I have somewhat of a problem. I have a slider (royal slider) with a customized skin. On the slider hover, the caption rises from the bottom, however, it only looks good if the caption is one line.

Is there a way I can make it rise from the same starting position from the bottom, that shows the entire caption for each slide, even if the amount of content is different for each slide.

```
/***************
*
*  8. Global caption
*
****************/
.custom-smc .rsGCaption {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;

    background: #BD3333;

    color: #fff ;
    padding: 13px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;

    font-size: 12px;

opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;



}

#new-royalslider-7:hover .rsGCaption {


opacity:.9;
transform: translate(0,-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-30px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-30px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-30px);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is now to set the bottom down:

```
.custom-smc .rsGCaption {
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

and on hover move it upwards

```
#new-royalslider-7:hover .rsGCaption {
    transform: translate(0,-30px);
}
```

This is difficult to adapt to different sizes of the rsGCaption.

One way to solve it is using the posibility to set the transform in percentage, instead of pixels. And leave the bottom at 0px, that is the only know position that will be independent of content:

```
.rsGCaption {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #BD3333;
    color: #fff ;
    padding: 13px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,100%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,100%);
    transform: translate(0,100%);
}

#new-royalslider-7:hover .rsGCaption {
    opacity:.9;
    transform: translate(0,0%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0%);
}
```

Notice that now we need 2 sets of transforms, the initial state is the "transformed" and the hover state needs to be reset.